# Как правильно импортировать модуль JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webpack, сборка

В проекте имеется директория `frontend` следующей структуры:

```
├── common
    ├── static
           ├── css
           ├── js
                └── common.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── app
    ├── static
           ├── css
           ├── js
                └── script1.js
                └── script2.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

Классы и некоторые методы, которые я определил в `common.js`, мне нужны в `script1.js` и `script2.js`. Я их импортировал как

```
 import './common/static/js/common.js'
 import { Class1, Class2 } from './common/static/js/common.js'
```

Но при сборке `webpack --display-error-details` сообщает об отсутвующем модуле

```
ERROR in ./app/static/app/js/settings.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./common/static/js/common.js in      .../frontend/app/static/table/js resolve file

 .../frontend/app/static/table/js/common/static/js/common.js doesn't exist
```

То есть webpack ищет файл в том же каталоге, где располгается вызывающий скрипт, а не каталог `frontend`.

Я понимаю, что могу задать инструкцию импорта вида `../../../../../../script.js`, но это выглядит не очень.

Можно сделать так, чтобы webpack искал относительно заданного мной каталога, в данном случае `frontend`?

Сейчас часть конфига с `resolve` выглядит так:

```
resolve: {
        moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        extension: ['', '.js', '.styl']
},
```

---

Дополнение. Импорт прошел успешно только после того, как добавил в конфиг директорию с импортируемым скриптом:

```
resolve: {
    root: [
        path.resolve('./common/static/js'),
    ],
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    extension: ['', '.js', '.styl']
},
```

Почему добавляется в качестве корня этот каталог и не добавляется каталог, в котором лежит конфиг?

---

Ошибка исправлена - неправильно записывал импорты.  Настройки вебпака из ответа [Утки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14963/%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%A3%D0%BC%D1%83)

```
 resolve: {
    root: [
        path.resolve(__dirname),
    ],
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    extension: ['', '.js', '.styl']
},
```

Поправил импорт

```
import { capitalizeFirstLetter, formatString } from 'common/static/js/common.js';
import { elementByClass, elementById } from 'common/static/js/common.js'
```

Comment: 1, добавил текущий resolve в вопрос

Comment: а я добавил ответ. Надо root в resolve прописать

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка ошибся, у меня 1. 2 имеет преимущества?

Comment: да и нет. Киллер фича webpack 2 - tree shaking. Некий алгоритм который по идее должен выкидывать из билда неиспользуемый код, уменьшая бандл. Может быть полезно на больших проектах. Но он гораздо хуже документирован (по крайней мере был пару месяцев назад) и достаточно сыр.

Comment: Я пока еще использую первый вебпак, в том числе на работе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для webpack 1 (то есть текущего стабильного документированного) нужно добавить `root` в секцию `resolve`:

```
var path = require('path');

resolve: {
  root: [
    path.resolve('yourRoot')
  ]
},
```

`yourRoot` - расположение желаемого корня. Например текущую директорию для webpack.config.js можно взять так: `path.resolve(__dirname)`

`path` - родной нодовский модуль, ставить отдельно не надо.

Comment: странно, добавил path.resolve('./frontend'), где frontend - директория с конфигом вебпака. ошибка аналогична, он пытается искать в каталоге модуля, который импортирует

Comment: @while1pass на самом деле я некорректно написал "относительно webpack.config.js". Ну то есть это путь относительно webpack.config.js если вы запускаете его из той же папки или если определяете путь черзе __dirname. В общем попробуйте path.resolve(__dirname)

Comment: спасибо за пояснение! я вижу, что ответ правильный, уже нашел его документации. но возвращает ту жу ошибку. запускаю сборщик из директории расположения конфига

Comment: @while1pass с ходу проблемы не вижу, попробуем отладиться. Напишите в файлике с конфигом перед конфигом: console.log(path.resolve(__dirname)). Вебпак конфиг - это просто js файл, который исполняется на ноде. Консоль лог в ноде тоже есть. Лог выводит в консоль нужную папку?

Comment: Ну собственно если не выводит  ничего - почему-то запускается не тот конфиг. 
Выведет не нужную папку - надо поменять путь. Выведет нужную - надо изучить весь конфиг.

Comment: да, каталог корректно выводится в консоль ~/myproject/src/frontend

Comment: оке, спасибо. буду копать

Comment: Импорт прошел успешно только после того, как добавил в конфиг директорию с импортируемым скриптом. Почему добавляется в качестве корня этот каталог и не добавляется каталог, в котором лежит конфиг?

Comment: @while1pass, да черт его знает, надо отлаживать. Может например в этом проблема: https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#windows-paths
Если указать путь как здесь, тоже не работает?

Comment: попробовал варианты ./frontend и __dirname ничего не изменилось, оставлю пока мое промежуточное решение. вернусь, как больше узнаю

Comment: разобрался, неправильно записывал импорт. поменял import { Class } from './common/static/js/common.js' на import { Class } from 'common/static/js/common.js'

Comment: @while1pass, аааааа ну да, понятно, у вас в самом файле были импорты написаны относительно текущего файла а не относительно рута, бывает)

Comment: всего лишь нужно было выспаться)