# Передать переменную из js файла в другой js файл

Tags: javascript

Не получается применить переменную в другом js файле. Для активации кнопки перенес всю ее функцию в другой файл

```
let timer = function() {
getPlayerHealth = player.health
getEnemyHealth = enemy.health
if (getPlayerHealth > 0 && getEnemyHealth <= 0) {
  myTimer = setInterval(game.makeFightEnviroment, 5000);
}
};
let getWildClass = document.querySelector(".wildOff");
let changeButtonId = function() {
  getWildClass.setAttribute("class", "wildOn");
};
getWildClass.addEventListener("click", timer);
getWildClass.addEventListener("click", changeButtonId);
```

На выходе при нажатии на кнопку выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'health' of undefined
player.health и enemy.health находятся изначально в другом файле
Какая есть возможность использовать скрипт выше? Весь интернет перерыл и ничего не нашел.

Comment: Дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/606673/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c-javascript)
[2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614107/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-js-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я правильно понимаю, тебе нужно гуглить import/export переменных

Comment: а js поддерживает такое? Просто я только начал его изучать и ничего особо не знаю. Знаю, что в питоне импорты используются, а вот в js ни разу не видел

Comment: @Ryuk в ecmascript 2015 ввели нативные import/export

Answer (score 0):

отловить событие в файле который надо передать ,или переписать функцию или довавить в нее данные ,или писать все в нужном файле
если по порядку подключить правильно,то будет в нужном файле так же как мы работаем с jquery